# Android emulator not displaying anything

Tags: android, emulation

I am new to android just installed Android sdk with eclipse & ADT plugin, these stuff are working fine, but my emulator doesn't display anything after 30 minutes.
My target virtual device(AVD)
Android 4.0.3, API level-15
CPU/ABI: armeabi-v7a
I have tried tweak from stack overflow
"Hardware section:Device RAM Size=15", It helped because before trying it, emulator was crashing. Now emulator appears but nothing is displayed
Please help it is depressing start this way

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the solution, the problem was i haven't set environment variable, which was "C:\Program Files\Android\android-sdk\platform-tools\" in my case,

Answer (score 1):

There is an intermittent problem with the emulator that we've encountered in our testing. It seems to happen the first time an AVD is run.

If you don't see the main screen within a few minutes, you should force-kill the emulator, stop adb with 'adb kill-server' from a command line. Restart adb with 'adb start-server' and then restart the emulator with your AVD. Suggest also to turn off the snapshot until the first time it loads correctly. If you're using the GPU feature, turn it off as well.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing same problem. I solved it as below steps.

Go to AVD manager, select the corresponding AVD, then click on edit then select the device from the drop down menu. I forget to select the device, so there was nothing on my AVD. Only black screen was there.